# How do I retrieve an attribute's name using the nodeName property?

Tags: javascript

You can easily retrieve the tag name of an element using the `nodeName`, like this:

```js
var atnode = document.getElementById("link-test");
alert(atnode.nodeName);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link-test">link</a>
```

But how do I use the `nodeName` to get the attribute of the element instead?

Using the `getAttribute()` does not do what I want, because you have to insert the name of the attribute first, and then it just gives you back the value of the attribute. I want to get the name of the attribute just like I did with `nodeName`. I know `nodeName` can be used with attribute nodes too, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of the attributes with `getAttributeNames()` on the node. In your example, you could do like so:

`atnode.getAttributeNames()` This will return `["href", "id"]`.

Then you can loop through the list with `getAttribute(<item from list as string>)` to get the values of the element's attributes.

Comment: I had never heard of that method before. Can I ask you something else though, why is it that, this method `getAttributeNames()` does not work on a variable that stores a collection of tag names? For example, `var tagcollect = document.getElementsByTagName("a")`. Now, the `tagcollect` is a reference to the  `a` elements, so why does `tagcollect.getAttributeNames()` does not return the names of all the attributes of these stored `a` elements that are references?

Comment: Because you need to call it on a single node. So you need to loop through the collection and then call the single item in the loop with `getAttributeNames()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const atnode = document.getElementById("link-test");
const nodes=[];
const values=[];

for (let att, i = 0, atts = atnode.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
    att = atts[i];
    nodes.push(att.nodeName);
    values.push(att.nodeValue);
    console.log(att.nodeName + " - " + att.nodeValue);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link-test">link</a>
```

After using attributes method you can use nodeName to get the attribute name and nodeValue to get the value of the attribute.
After pushing it to array you can get attribute and value of it using same index in both arrays.

Comment: You are using stuff that I haven't studied yet. I have not studied the `push` method before, and the `attributes` method. Also, I am curious, why are the variable outside the loop created with `const` but the `att` inside created with `let`? Also, is `atts` a global variable? Why did you not define it?

Comment: Push method works with arrays, you pass a parameter and it pushes it to the array given, when you use const variables than you can't change it (or the refernce with some data types), i used let in the for loop because as you see i change the variable, except atts and n that could be constants also, but it doesn't really matter in this case. and no atts is NOT a global variable, there is something that called block scope since ES6 (with let and const). @Ihateselfmoderation

Comment: So when did you define `atts` then? You never defined it anywhere, so doesn't that make it a global variable?

Comment: @Ihateselfmoderation In the beginning of the for loop, you can see there is a let keyword and then i define 4 variables: att, i, atts and n.

Comment: oh, I get it now. I am guessing you can't do that with var, right? Can you create multiple variables like that using var too?

Comment: @Ihateselfmoderation Yes you can actually, i try to use ES6 for convenience and because i got used to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you just need to use the [getAttributeNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames) method.

Follows an example:

```js
const exampleElement = document.getElementsByTagName("example")[0];
console.log(exampleElement.getAttributeNames());
```

```html
<example name="one" last="two"></example>
```